# Is there a way to make graphic movement smooth without increasing refresh rate?

Tags: flash, animation, graphics

In a typical flash envioroment,the frame rate is 24.

If perform an object moving from A to B in 2 seconds,and the two points is 600 pixels away, which means the object must move 600/(24*2) = 12.5 pixels every frame.That makes the movement like jumping or lagging,the effect isn't good enough.

One solution is increasing the frame rate, If set it to 60, the speed would be 5 pixels per frame,it looks much better.

Another solution is decrease the speed, If set it down to 2 or 1 pixels/frame, It will looks smooth,but in this way will change the requirement which is not acceptable.

Since change the whole project's framerate risk is high, I was trying to solve this problem without change the frame rate.

What i tried is ease moving, the code basiclly looks like below

```
obj.x -= destX/10;
obj.y -= destY/10;
```

and i tried to improve it in various ways,for example , start the process from zero vector to make the moving more naturally ,but no any of effects can reach the level of increasing refresh rate.

After ten hours work i began to doubt such problem can't be fixed at this frame rate.

If it is true,i will give up in this way.if it is false, any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The human brain can view around 60 frames per second. I see no reason why increasing the frame rate is risky. Movements larger than around 10-20 pixels per frame don't look so good. Increasing the frame rate is probably the only option you have.

If you really want to avoid increasing the frame rate, then the only other thing you could do is to add motion blur, however that won't make much difference.